# NameError when running in `main` module

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to grab all the `.md` files recursively within files.To complish it,I define a recursive function which run in a `main` module.

The code:

```
import os
def walk(dirname):
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            if '.md' in path:
                path_list.append(path)
        else:
            walk(path)
    return path_list
def main():
    dir = '/Users/Documents/Diary'
    path_list = []
    path = walk(dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running, it reports:

```
NameError: name 'path_list' is not defined
```

However, if running without of  `main()`, it works:

```
In [80]: path_list = []
    ...: def walk(dirname):
    ...:     for name in os.listdir(dirname):
    ...:         path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
    ...:         if os.path.isfile(path):
    ...:             if '.md' in path:
    ...:                 path_list.append(path)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             walk(path)
    ...:     return path_list
```

output:

```
dir = '/Users/Documents/Diary'
walk(dir)
Out[81]:
['/Users/Documents/Diary/py4.1.If_statements.md',
 '/Users/Documents/Diary/pyName_and_object:.md',
 ...]
```

I have no idea what's the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option declares `path_list` as a global variable, so it is known in all functions.

You could also declare it in the `walk()` function, the only place where it is needed. But, as commented, since that function is called recursively, that would reset the list every time, instead of aggregating the results.

See more at "[Notes on Python variable scope](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/)".

> Global variables are accessible inside and outside of functions.
> Local variables are only accessible inside the function.
> If I set a variable in a function with the same name as a global variable, I am actually creating a new local variable.

Comment: How to declare it in the walk () function? it recursively to call itself.When encounter nested directory,`def walk(): path_list=[]`. path_list's value will be cleared every time it  is recursively called.

Comment: True, then a global declaration is enough

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that of scope of object.

When you make a `main()` function, you are declaring `path_list` in the local scope of `main()`. Hence it is not available to `walk()` function.

You have to pass `path_list` as an argument to walk or declare it globally as you did latter to make it available. As of current, `path_list` is out of scope of `walk()`.

Comment: impressive ,cannot believe your reputation is 1 :-

Comment: Thanks, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `path_list` in the `walk` function, as it is the function that is operating on it. You get an error because you don't have any `path_list` pre-declared in that function.

Moreover, you don't need to define any `path_list` in the main function because it does not operate on it an doesn't need it.

When you declare it globally, it is available to all the functions, even the `walk` function. It uses that global variable and you don't get any error.